# Greenplum Database : enabling PL/Python module

Tags: python, database, greenplum, plpython

I'm on Version 6.6.14 of Greenplum  and trying to enable python 3. When I try to enable it with this command:

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/plpython3": No such file or directory

Any I idea on how to get  python3 enabled ?

Answer (score 0):

refer to [this guide](https://docs.greenplum.org/6-6/analytics/pl_python.html)

> The Greenplum Database PL/Python extension is installed by default with Greenplum Database. Greenplum Database installs a version of Python and PL/Python. This is location of the Python installation that Greenplum Database uses:

```
$GPHOME/ext/python/
```

You have to enable it with `admin / Su` rights

```
$ psql -d testdb -c 'CREATE EXTENSION plpythonu;'
```

Answer (score 0):

The version installed with Greenplum is version 2.7 but you can install python3 into pl/container and use it that way.